# Using Variables and Dynamic SQL in View

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-view

Say I have 4 databases all on the same SQL server (2012), named Business, Customer1, Customer2 and Config (not real names, just trying to keep the example clear).

Several 'Customer' databases could belong to the same 'Business', this relationship is defined in the 'Config' database.

I need to put a table in the 'Business' database, and have it accessible in the Customer databases. So for example

```
USE Business
SELECT * FROM Users
```

would yield the same results as

```
USE Customer1
SELECT * FROM Users
```

would yield the same results as

```
USE Customer2
SELECT * FROM Users
```

I figure this is easily achievable using a view, so in each customer database:

```
CREATE VIEW Users --(I know this naming is wrong, and I should clearly name the view as such, but I'm trying to limit impact to existing code)
AS
SELECT * FROM [Business]..Users
```

The problem I have is there will be loads of 'Business' databases, so I really need my view to take notice of the business-customer relationship, and be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW Users
AS
DECLARE @BusinessDB varchar(50) = 
(SELECT BusinessDB FROM Config..Business where CustomerID = (SELECT Value FROM SysInfo where KeyName = 'CustomerID'))

EXEC('SELECT * FROM ['+@BusinessDB+']..Users')
```

EXCEPT I can't declare / use variables in a view.

Does anyone know a way of achieving my goal, or am I going to have to maintain slightly different views for each business?

Thanks

Comment: Can you simply replace the concept of selecting from a view with the concept of executing a proc that returns the desired results?

Comment: Not really, since I need to be able to update and insert also, and 'trick' existing code into thinking it's still accessing the table directly.

Comment: But you can't insert/update a view unless it's schemabound anyway, and good luck with that.  However, you could make a view that does UNION ALL of subselects from all your user tables WHERE [BusDB from Config]=[The DB the User table lives in].  Disadvantage is you will have to modify the view every time you add a new DB.